# How to retrieve token as string from storage (string.split error)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I keep getting a `string.split` error trying to get the issued at time using `jwtHelper` `jwtHeler.decodeToken(token).iat`. How can I retrieve the token as as a string instead of promise?

This is what I get when I log `token`

```
t {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state:true
__zone_symbol__value:"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzMjkiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9wcm9qZWN0cy5zdGFybGluZXdpbmRvd3MuY29tXC9yZWZyZXNoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTAxMTY
```

Refresh Function

```
public scheduleRefresh() {

    let source = this.authHttp.tokenStream.flatMap(
      token => {
        console.log("token=", token);
        let jwtIat = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token).iat;
        let jwtExp = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token).exp;
        let iat = new Date(0);
        let exp = new Date(0);

        let delay = (exp.setUTCSeconds(jwtExp) - iat.setUTCSeconds(jwtIat));

        return Observable.interval(delay);
      });

    this.refreshSubscription = source.subscribe(() => {
      this.refresh().subscribe((res) => console.log('-> Refreshed...'), 
      (error) => console.log('Refresh error: ' + JSON.stringify(error)))
    });
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
export function getAuthHttp(http, storage) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    headerName: 'Authorization',
    headerPrefix: 'Bearer',
    noJwtError: true,
    globalHeaders: [{'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}],
    tokenGetter: (() =>   storage.ready().then(() => storage.get('token')))
  }), http);
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get an answer for this? I'm getting the same when saving the token to localstorage and when trying to get the token it returns in an array containing __zone_symbol__state and __zone_symbol__state

Comment: i have the same issue here, any updates ?